# loop homology product for oriented compact manifolds with boundary

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

This is my first steeps in string topology and please forgive the basic level of my questions: I reformulate my question

Chas and Sullivan define the loop homology product for closed (=compact with no boundary) and oriented maniflods. Is there such loop homology product for oriented compact manifolds with boundary

Comment: In your question 2: Do you really want your manifold to be contractible?

Comment: In Question 1, isomorphic as what? It's elementary as vector spaces since the G action allows you to split the usual free loop based loop fibration sequence. If you want to include some extra structure you should check that the iso you get in this way respects the extra structure. In question 2: why contractible?

Comment: For question 1: isomorphic as algebra. Question 2 can be surely asked in a general case, however   my frameworks require manifolds to be contractible

Comment: I am really puzzled by your requirement that the manifold be contractible. A closed manifold (=compact with no boundary) is never contractible, except if it is zero-dimensional, in which case it is a point. Do you maybe have some different meaning in mind for the words "closed" and "contractible"?

Comment: @AndréHenriques: Thanks for pointing my attention to this. In fact my frameworks is contractible manifold, so I will reformulate my question as follows: closeness of the manifold is necessary to define the loop homology product (as defined by Chas-Sullivan) for compact manifold

Comment: Contractible manifolds (assuming they are not a point) are of two types: (1) compact with boundary, and (2) non-compact without boundary. Which type of contractible manifolds are you studying?

Comment: I think the question is now reasonable, and I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

Edit 1: In a first version there was a question about string topology of Lie groups.

A very good reference about string topology of Lie groups is 
"String Topology for Lie Groups."
J. Topology (2010) 3(2): 424-442
by Richard Hepworth.

The main point concerning your first question is to understand how to describe the BV-operator (the $S^1$-action) on $\mathbb{H}(G)\otimes H(\Omega G)$. Luc Menichi has also a nice paper on that theme:
"A Batalin-Vilkovisky algebra morphism from double loop spaces to free loops",  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 363 (2011), 4443-4462.

..............................................

Edit 1 (continued):

- You can extend the definition of the Chas-Sullivan loop product to open manifolds even when they are non-orientable (by using a local coefficient system). In order to do so you can use the same techniques as in Chas-Sullivan's original paper.  If you want more details look at François Laudenbach's note
  "A note on the Chas-Sullivan product." Enseign. Math. (2) 57 (2011) 
  In the non-compact case you will loose the unit.
- Another funny thing to do when you have a manifold with boundary is to consider the space $L_{\partial M} M$ of loops $\gamma$ in $M$ such that $\gamma(0)$ is on the boundary $\partial M$. Then you get an algebra $H_{*+dim(\partial M)}(L_{\partial M} M)$ mixing the intersection product on the boundary and the pontryagin algebra of based loops $H_*(\Omega M)$.

.....................................................

Edit 2: Concerning your first question, you can compare François Laudenbach's definition (which is so close in spirit to the very first definition of the loop product) with Cohen-Jones' definition in terms of Gysin maps and with Dennis Sullivan's definition given in his paper "String Topology: Background and Present State", they all give isomorphic algebra structures at the homology level. The proof follows the same lines as in the case of the classical intersection product.

Comment: After reading Laudenbach's notes, I've some more basic questions: **Question 1:** In the case of  closed and oriented maniflods, the Chas-Sullivan loop product and that of Laudenbach are the same?if yes why? **Question 2:** The loop homology once endowed with the Laudenbach product is just an associative and commutative graded ring. Why not an algebra? maybe because that the cofficients are twisted?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your question 2.

Comment: In the framwork of Chas-Sullivan the loop product endows the loop homology $\mathbb{H}_*(LM;\mathbb Z)$ with an associative and commutative graded algebra. In that of Laudenbach, the coefficients system is twisted due to some orientation, and here the loop product endows the loop homology $\mathbb{H}_*(LM;\mathbb Z_{or})$ with an associative and commutative graded ring. Why not an algebra as in the Chas-Sullivan context?

Comment: $\mathbb{H}_*(LM,\mathbb{k}_{or})$ is a $\mathbb{k}$-algebra for any commutative ring $\mathbb{k}$.

Comment: Thanks David. Is there any thing known about $\mathbb{H}(LM,\mathbb{k}_{or})$ in the special case when $M$ is contractible.

Comment: If $M$ is contractible, $LM$ is also contractible, everything is trivial.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are interested by contractible manifolds.

Comment: Because that my framework is on Topological Robotics (in the sense of Farber view point) which requires manifolds to be contractible, and if not to recover it by some given open and contractible subsets

Comment: In fact you are not interested by contractible manifolds. $TC(X)=1$ if and only if $X$ is contractible, but by covers of manifolds. And I suppose that you are interested by relationships between numerical invariants and string topology invariants.

Comment: The project is in its first steep, we focus on the loop homology many ideas can emerge about cup length, .... Your idea is also really very interesting